# Camera Remote API transfer images

Tags: camera, sony

It is possible to transfer images from a Sony QX10 to a desktop    application, which uses the Camera Remote API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the QX10 will allow you to take a picture and retrieve the url of the picture right away, you are not able to get a list of images on the Camera using the API.